# Segurança no Login com PHP e AJAX com segurança no direcionamento

Tags: php, ajax, aplicação-web, segurança

Precisei recentemente fazer um sistema de login com níveis de acesso, porém ao direcionar o usuário para determinada página me bateu uma dúvida em relação a segurança do código. Ignore as validações, vou mostrar apenas a parte que me bateu a dúvida...

Eu sempre fiz da seguinte forma:

```
//JS 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnEntrar").click(function(){

        //Recebendo os dados do formulário
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var senha = $("#senha").val();

        //Enviando dados para o PHP
        $.post('valida-login.php',
                {email : email, senha : senha},

            //Resposta do PHP
            function(retorno){

                // Validação OK
                if (retorno == 'nivel_1') {

                    // Mensagem
                    $('.retorno').html('Login sucesso!');
                    setTimeout(function(){ location.href = "cpanel-adm.php"; }, 2000);

                }else{

                    // Mensagem
                    $('.retorno').html('Login sucesso!');
                    setTimeout(function(){ location.href = "cpanel-clt.php"; }, 2000);

                }
            })
        }
        return false;
    })
})
```

**Arquivo valida-login.php**

```
<?php 

//Sessão iniciada
session_start();

//Recebendo o formulário via Post pelo Ajax
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

//Fui no banco e verifiquei o nível de usuário

if(nivel == 1){

   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
   echo 'nivel_1';

}else{

    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    echo 'nivel_2';
}
?>
```

**Isso aí funciona de boas e tem vários exemplos assim na web.
Agora a outra maneira que encontrei é fazendo o direcionamento dessa forma:**

```
//OBSERVE QUE A FUNÇÃO DE RETORNO NÃO DIZ NADA DE DIRECIONAMENTO DE PÁGINA
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#btnEntrar").click(function(){

            //Recebendo os dados do formulário
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var senha = $("#senha").val();

            //Enviando dados para o PHP
            $.post('valida-login.php',
                    {email : email, senha : senha},

                //Resposta do PHP
                function(retorno){

                    // Validação OK
                    $('.retorno').html(retorno);

                })
            }
            return false;
        })
    })
```

**E o direcionamento agora é feito "escondido" no PHP:**

```
<?php 

    //Sessão iniciada
    session_start();

    //Recebendo o formulário via Post pelo Ajax
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

    //Fui no banco e verifiquei o nível de usuário

    if(nivel == 1){

       $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
       echo "<script> document.location = 'cpanel-adm.php' </script>";

    }else{

        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        echo "<script> document.location = 'cpanel-clt.php' </script>";
    }
    ?>
```

Gostaria de saber se isso é opcional ou determinada forma é errada e tende a ser mais propícia a futuros ataques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retorne apenas a url de redirect e coloque a role na sessão, e não o  no meio do PHP.

E você pode fazer uma função (ou na construct) um validador de nível de acesso com a role da sessão, se você inverter a ordem (1 usuário e 2 admin), fica mais fácil de você trabalhar.

**JS**

```
if(retorno != 'error')
   window.location.href = retorno;
```

**PHP**

```
$data = $_POST;

//Fui no banco e verifiquei o nível de usuário
if( in_array($nivel, [1,2]) ):
   $_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];
   $_SESSION['role']  = $nivel;
endif;

switch ($nivel) {
    case 1:
        print 'cpanel-clt.php';
        break;
    case 2:
        print 'cpanel-adm.php';
        break;
    default:
        print 'error';
        break;
}
```

Depois disso, tu pode fazer uma função e chamar onde necessário, mais ou menos assim:

```
//SOMENTE ADMIN ACESSA
verificar_nivel(2);

//FUNÇÃO
public function verificar_nivel($nivel_minimo = 1) {

   if(!isset($_SESSION['role']) || $_SESSION['role'] < $nivel_minimo)
      header("Location: logout.php");

}
```

Comment: Entendi Matheus, legal! Bem diferente do que eu havia pensado. Mas a forma que eu fiz você considerada insegura ou errada? Ou é apenas diferente do que você fez?